# CSS with gtk 3.22.25 do not operate

Tags: c, gtk3

hello dear enthousiasm gtk guy

a small code in order to explain my problem
with gtk 3.10.8 code belox run ok with blue window

```
/* Compile with: 
*       gcc -Wall windox_css.c -o windox_css `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`                     
*/
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
/*--- CSS -----------------*/
  GtkCssProvider *provider;
  GdkDisplay *display;
  GdkScreen *screen;
/*-------------------------*/
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW(window),
                               500, 300);

  g_signal_connect (GTK_WIDGET(window),
                    "destroy",
                    G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit),
                    NULL);

/*------  CSS  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
  display = gdk_display_get_default ();
  screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);

  gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen,
                                 GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider),
                                 GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
//"-GtkWidget-focus-line-width: 0;\n"
  gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (GTK_CSS_PROVIDER(provider),
                                   " GtkWindow {\n"

                                   "   -GtkWindow-resize-grip-height: 0;\n"    /* not guaranteed, can be overridden by window manger */
                                   "   -GtkWindow-resize-grip-width: 0;\n"     /* not guaranteed, can be overridden by window manger */                       
                                   "   background-color: blue;\n"              /* named color units */
                                   "   background-color: rgb (0, 0, 255);\n"   /* rgb color units, overrides the previous "background-color" assignment */
                                   "   background-color: rgba (0,0,255,1);\n"  /* rgba color units, overrides the previous "background-color" assignment */
                                   "   background-color: #0000FF;\n"           /* hexadecimal color units, overrides the previous "background-color" assignment */
                                   "   background-color: shade(blue, 1.0);\n"  /* overrides previous color assignment */   
                                   "}\n", -1, NULL);
  g_object_unref (provider);
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  gtk_main ();
return (0);
}
```

with new version gtk 3.22.25 the window stay white.
What is about? could you help me to understand what I must change.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very easy to find in gtk+ reference. Since 3.20 css change.

all widget name as GtkLabel has a css name like label minus without Gtk !!!!
for example

```
gboolean css_flag_320 = check_gtk();

  if (css_flag_320)
  {
     gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (GTK_CSS_PROVIDER(provider),
                                   " window {\n"
                                   "   -widget-focus-line-width: 0;\n"
                                   "   -window-resize-grip-height: 0;\n"    /* not guaranteed, can be overridden by window manger */
                                   "   -window-resize-grip-width: 0;\n"     /* not guaranteed, can be overridden by window manger */   
                                   "   background-color: shade(darkgreen, 1.0);\n"    
                                   "}\n"
                                   "/*   gestion du bouton */\n"
                   "button {\n"
                       "background-image: -gtk-gradient (radial,\n"
                           "0.1 0.1, 0.2,\n"
                           "0.2 0.2, 1,\n"
                                   " from (lightgreen),\n"
                           " to (shade (red, 0.9)));\n"
                   " }\n"
                   "/*   gestion du bouton */\n"
                           "textview:active {\n"
                           "background-image: -gtk-gradient (radial,\n"
                           "0.1 0.1, 0.2,\n"
                           "0.2 0.2, 1,\n"
                           "from (red),\n"
                           "to (shade (yellow, 0.4)));\n"
                           "}\n"
                           "/*   gestion du dialogue */\n"
                           "dialog{color: black;font-size: 110%; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; }\n"
                           "dialog{background-color: pink; }\n"//color = #F00 ou pink
                           "/*   gestion du dialogue d'erreur */\n"
                           "messagedialog{color: black;font-size: 110%; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; }\n"
                           "messagedialog{background-color: orange; }\n"
                           "/*   mise en cohérence de couleur du scroll et du notebook conseillée */\n"
                           " .scrollwindow {color: red;}\n"
                           "/*   gestion du notebook */\n"
                           "notebook arrow:nth-child(first) { color: red ;}\n" // ne sert que pour le triangle du scrolling qui apparait en red
                           "notebook arrow:nth-child(last) { color: orange ;}\n" // ne sert que pour le triangle du scrolling qui apparait en red

                           "notebook  #normal {\n"  // normalement .notebook devrait être ok ???
                           "   padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;\n"
                           "   border-radius: 8px;\n"
                           "   background-color: shade(lightblue, 1.0);}\n"
                           "notebook #modified {\n"  // normalement .notebook devrait être ok ??? et .modified ne fonctionne pas
                           "   padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;\n"
                           "   border-radius: 8px;\n"
                           "   background-color: yellow;\n"
                           "}\n"
                           ".tooltip{background-color: yellow;}",
                           -1, NULL); //color = #f90192
```